# Diagnosing type of Javascript leak

Tags: javascript, datatables, profiler

I have a webpage with an "auto-refresh" feature. When turned on, every one second a page is fetched via ajax (called page_request) and replaces the contents of a div container with the provided containerid:

```
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
```

This works most of the time, no problem.

The problem arises when the following script is in page_response:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        dtable = $('#multi-stat-table').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

This script turns the table with the id "multi-stat-table" into a sortable table using the DataTables jQuery plugin. The script works, and I have sortable tables. However, if auto-refresh is on, there is a memory leak that will eventually consume the whole heap (slowly, but surely).

I can see this phenomena using both top and chrome's memory profiler. Every one second, ~70 KB data is allocated, but only ~20 KB is freed. Hence, there is a net loss of 50 KB heap memory per second. I've looked through the objects in the profiler that are taking up memory, but it is very difficult to figure out from the non-descript numbers what these arrays and Objects are actually referencing. I have been unable to figure out how to make the garbage collector collect these unused objects that are piling up every second:

[image: Memory Leak]

I've tried setting dtable to null before each auto-refresh, to no avail. I've also tried calling dtable.api().clear() and dtable.api().destroy(), but the leak persists. How can I find this leak, and more importantly, what can I do to stop it?

Comment: Sticking fragments of HTML from the server containing script tags into the middle of your page even once, not to mention once a minute, seems like a remarkably creative way to cause all sorts of bad things to happen.

Comment: I know, but it's "Legacy Code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pinpoint the exact cause of the memory leak.

I first had the idea that it could be a jQuery caching problem when I was looking through Chrome's profiler and saw that jQuery's cache object was referencing 45 MB worth of objects. After a bit of research, this is the article I read that helped me figure out how to fix it: http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#jquery-anti-leak-measures-and-leaks

Before I was doing this:
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText; //Dangerous if anything inside of containerid is referenced by jQuery later!

After the fix:
$("#container").html(page_request.responseText); // html() dereferences unused objects cached inside of containerid

Note to self: It can be dangerous to mix and match jQuery and non-jQuery DOM